Browser issues workaround for the "Review Question" button not working?
Every so often on Safari (v16.2 - haven't tried other versions, and yes, I'm due for an update), the "Review Question" button doesn't do anything.  Surprisingly, a page reload doesn't fix it either.
It's easy enough to just open up another browser, because everything I entered into the "Ask Question" interface in Safari shows up.  All I have to do is click "Review Question", and I'm off and running.
I'm just wondering if there's an alternate workaround so I don't have to wait for Chrome to load (which is also surprisingly slow).
It's possible that this could be related to the Web Inspector window (which automatically logs me out of my stack account.
In fact, the bug happened as I tried to review this question.  I peeked at the console and I have the following error:


TL;DR: by design, SE does not support Safari 16 anymore, not even for the most basic action of posting question.

Related (MSO): Unable to ask a question using Safari. Safari 15.3. A comment: "Since Chrome dropped support for macOS v10.14 and below back in September of 2023, you might try checking out the Chromium-legacy project, -

cont' - which aims to support up-to-date Chromium on macOS versions unsupported by Chrome itself. I am not affiliated or anything, but I recently ran across the project and now use it on my old v10.13 Mac, and found it super useful."

And "the oldest version of Safari which Stack Overflow, currently, supports is 17.3."

TBF, I wasn't asking for a bug fix or support for Safari 16, I was asking for a workaround, but whatever.

Workaround is to update, yeah.

That's arguable.  Opening Chrome is also a workaround. It was clear I pointed both of those out, so clearly I was asking for another workaround, but again, whatever.
